# What is futures::future::lazy for?

Tags: rust, future, rust-tokio

In the [Tokio documentation](https://tokio.rs/docs/futures/spawning/) we have this snippet:

```rust
extern crate tokio;
extern crate futures;

use futures::future::lazy;

tokio::run(lazy(|| {
    for i in 0..4 {
        tokio::spawn(lazy(move || {
            println!("Hello from task {}", i);
            Ok(())
        }));
    }

    Ok(())
}));
```

The explanation for this is:

> The `lazy` function runs the closure the first time the future is polled. It is used here to ensure that `tokio::spawn` is called from a task. Without `lazy`, `tokio::spawn` would be called from outside the context of a task, which results in an error.

I'm not sure I understand this precisely, despite having some familiarity with Tokio. It seems that these two `lazy` have slightly different roles, and that this explanation only applies to the *first* one. Isn't the second call to `lazy` (inside the `for` loop) just here to convert the closure into a future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *purpose* of lazy is covered by the [documentation for `lazy`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.27/futures/future/fn.lazy.html):

> Creates a new future which will eventually be the same as the one created by the closure provided.
>
> The provided closure is only run once the future has a callback scheduled on it, otherwise the callback never runs. Once run, however, this future is the same as the one the closure creates.

Like a plain closure, it's used to prevent code from being eagerly evaluated. In synchronous terms, it's the difference between calling a function and calling the closure that the function returned:

```
fn sync() -> impl FnOnce() {
    println!("This is run when the function is called");
    
    || println!("This is run when the return value is called")
}

fn main() {
    let a = sync();
    println!("Called the function");
    a();
}
```

And the parallel for futures 0.1:

```
use futures::{future, Future}; // 0.1.27

fn not_sync() -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> {
    println!("This is run when the function is called");

    future::lazy(|| {
        println!("This is run when the return value is called");
        Ok(())
    })
}

fn main() {
    let a = not_sync();
    println!("Called the function");
    a.wait().unwrap();
}
```

With `async`/`await` syntax, this function should not be needed anymore:

```
#![feature(async_await)] // 1.37.0-nightly (2019-06-05)

use futures::executor; // 0.3.0-alpha.16
use std::future::Future;

fn not_sync() -> impl Future<Output = ()> {
    println!("This is run when the function is called");

    async {
        println!("This is run when the return value is called");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = not_sync();
    println!("Called the function");
    executor::block_on(a);
}
```

As you've identified, Tokio's examples use `lazy` to:

- ensure that the code in the closure is only run from inside the executor.
- ensure that a closure is run as a future

I view these two aspects of `lazy` as effectively the same.

See also:

- [Why does calling tokio::spawn result in the panic "SpawnError { is_shutdown: true }"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54503625/155423)
- [What is the purpose of async/await in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52835725/155423)

Comment: Thanks, I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54503625/why-does-calling-tokiospawn-result-in-the-panic-spawnerror-is-shutdown-tru answered my question. I should have mentioned that I've read the doc for `lazy` but haven't really understood it (what does "having a callback scheduled on it" mean? and what are we supposed to see from the "example" snippet?).

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer, it's much clearer now!